# Django - add link with custom admin page href

Tags: django

In my Django project, I have created a custom admin page for an app via the `get_urls()` method. I'd like to add a link to the app's main model index view that will take users to this custom page - however, I'm having some trouble creating this link element correctly and I don't seem to be able to piece together the right way to do it - I'm just left with a `Reverse for 'export' not found. 'export' is not a valid view function or pattern name.` error.

I've set up the admin for the app like so:

```
# my_project/observations/admin.py

from django.template.response import TemplateResponse
from django.urls import path

class ObservationAdmin(SimpleHistoryAdmin, SoftDeletionModelAdmin):
    change_list_template = 'export_link.html'

    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super().get_urls()
        custom_urls = [
            path('export/', self.admin_site.admin_view(self.export_view), name='export')
        ]

        return custom_urls + urls

    def export_view(self, request):
        context = dict(
           self.admin_site.each_context(request),
        )

        return TemplateResponse(request, 'export.html', context)
```

and the two templates that are referenced:

```
# my_project/observations/templates/export.html

{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div>
    Some custom content
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

```
# my_project/observations/templates/export_link.html

{% extends 'admin/change_list.html' %}

{% block object-tools-items %}
    <li>
        <a href="{% url 'export' %}" class="btn btn-high btn-success">Export</a>
    </li>
    {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```

Navigating directly to `http://localhost:8000/admin/observations/observation/export/` works perfectly, I see the custom content page exactly as I want it... so the issue I'm striking is with the link template - I get the `Reverse...` error when I navigate to the model index page.

Perhaps the argument I'm passing to `url` is incorrect, or I need to register that URL elsewhere - but I don't quite know. The other examples of link elements like this that I've been able to find don't reference URLs created via the admin class' `get_urls()` method - so any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks very much, let me know if there's any other info that I can provide to help sort this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problems is in missing [namespace](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces) in your `export_link.html` template. Instead of:

```
<a href="{% url 'export' %}" class="btn btn-high btn-success">Export</a>
```

try:

```
<a href="{% url 'admin:export' %}" class="btn btn-high btn-success">Export</a>
```

Comment: Thank you! That's terrific - in other examples, I had seen that the namespacing was important, but I wasn't clear on how it would apply here. Much appreciated.